# Can I set the map style in Memgraph Lab using GSS?

Tags: memgraphdb, memgraph

Is there a way to use GSS code to force certain map type as background? I didn't find anything related to map styles in [Graph Style Script language specification](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-visualization/graph-style-script).

When I open Memgraph Lab I can manually select one of the map types: Detailed, Light, Dark, Basic or Satellite. How can I programmatically change the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by updating your GSS code and adding the [`@ViewStyle.Map` directive](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-visualization/graph-style-script/directive-properties#viewstylemap-directive). You can the define the style to be one of the following:

```
tile-layer: string: "detailed" | "light" | "dark" | "basic" | "satellite"
```